# dbfilename can't be a path, just a filename

Tags: redis, upgrade

I have a redis-db that has been recently upgraded from 2.6.16 to 3.0.7. When I try to bring up the instance, it spews the following logs :

Reading the configuration file, at line 15

> 'dbfilename "/var/db/sync_app/app_discovery/user.rdb"'
> dbfilename can't be a path, just a filename

When I go-ahead and change this config param to be just a file and not the entire path, it works and the redis-db instance comes up.

These links however say that the said issue has been fixed.

https://github.com/redis-store/testing/issues/1

So I'm a little confused. Is this fixed in 3.0.7 or not ? Do I need to make changes to the config files of all my redis instances for this upgrade to work?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with redis-store-testing. The configuration line you posted is definitely not coming from the gem.

For reference, here's where we were using the `dbfilename` setting: https://github.com/redis-store/testing/commit/31148dbeb7ac75fb22dd17085b26e921eac12542

Answer (score 1):

From `redis.conf`:

```
# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
#
# The Append Only File will also be created inside this directory.
#
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /var/lib/redis
```

`dir` sets the shared path for `dbfilename` and `appendfilename`.